# ¿Cómo partir una url y en función de la última parte del enlace que haya, intercambiar clases?

Tags: php, html, jquery, url

Tengo este pequeño problema, la cuestión es que en la primera funciona y me da la url correcta pero luego cuando voy a otra me sigue dando la misma url de la primera...
Lo que necesito es que en función de la url que haya yo pueda cambiar las clases para que a su vez se cambien los colores, si alguien tiene más experiencia y me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo. Este es mi código:

```js
$('a.enlacecategoria').ready(function () {
  var url = $('a.enlacecategoria').attr('href');

  var url_analizada = /^(\w+):\/\/([^\/]+)([^]+)$/.exec(url);
  var [, protocolo, servidor, path] = url_analizada;


  if ($path = '/ramblaprimmiche/Familia/administracio-i-gestio/') {

   $('#barra-color').addClass('ninguna')

  } else if ($path = '/ramblaprimmiche/Familia/electricitat-electronica/') {
   $('#barra-color').removeClass('bg-blue');
   $('#barra-color').addClass('bg-orange');
  } else if ($path = '/ramblaprimmiche/Familia/educacio-i-control-ambiental/') {
   $('#barra-color').removeClass('bg-blue');
   $('#barra-color').addClass('bg-green-estudio');
  } else if ($path = '/ramblaprimmiche/Familia/itineraris-formatius-especifics/') {
   $('#barra-color').removeClass('bg-blue');
   $('#barra-color').addClass('bg-red');
  } else if ($path = '/ramblaprimmiche/Familia/programes-de-formacio-i-insercio/') {
   $('#barra-color').removeClass('bg-blue');
   $('#barra-color').addClass('bg-sky');
  }


  alert($path);
 });
```

```css
.bg-blue {
    background-color: #46495C;
}

.bg-orange {
    background-color: #a15838;
}

.bg-green-estudio {
    background-color: #95aa45;
}

.bg-red {
    background-color: #9b3f4c;
}

.bg-sky {
    background-color: #5a95a5;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-box bg-burgundy color-custom-white text-left">

    <div id="barra-color" class="bg-blue wrapper-left float-left h-100">
        <h1 class="uppercase mb-0 invisible">a</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="header-cursos">
   
            <h1 class="uppercase mb-0 mx-3 taxonomia-single" id="categoriaActual">
                <?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'Familia', '', ', ' ); ?></h1>

            <h2 class="uppercase fs-15 mx-lg-0 mx-3"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que todos los enlaces tienen la clase "enlaceCategoria", es decir, hay varios de estos. En la función tu extraes la url del primer enlace y no del enlace porque haces referencia a **a.enlacecategoria** y no al que generó el evento. Debes usar `$(this).attr("href")`. Supongo que el evento es `click` y no `ready`.

Las comparaciones de los `if` son sentencias de asignación y no de comparación.

Verifica que la variable es `$parh`.

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que esta plantilla es una single-post de wordpress y lo que quiero es que cuando entren a un post que pertenece a "x" categoria cambie el color, por eso el evento es ready. el enlace siempre es el mismo. lo que hace wp es que le cambia la url en funcion de la categoria que pertenece, por es que apunto al enlace para cambiar de color

Comment: Pero sigo pensando que debería ser $(this) porque ese es el que genera el a.enlacecategoria. el evento es $('a.enlacecategoeia').ready() es decir que $(this) es $('a.enlacecategoeia'). Lo que estas haciendo alnasignar la url. Lo has probado convthis? Me perdí un poco los if los haces sin ==?

Comment: Si igual no me funciona...

Comment: Fíjate las comparaciones del  if (deben ser ==) por eso siemprenva por el primero y es path no $path. Si funciona me avisas para ponerlo en minrwapuesta

Comment: Siiii muchas gracias me ha funcionado!!